# How do I change MUI - Autocomplete component options styles

Tags: css, reactjs, typescript, user-interface, material-ui

So I've been trying to change the bg-color of selected options in the Autocomplete tag in material-ui. I've had success soo far and it looks like this.

[image]

```js
renderOption={(params, { selected }) => {
            return (
              <div
                key={params.id}
                style={{
                  height: '40px',
                  display: 'flex',
                  width: '100%',
                  justifyContent: 'space-between',
                  alignItems: 'center',
                }}
              >
                <div
                  style={{
                    gap: '1rem',
                    alignItems: 'center',
                    display: 'flex',
                  }}
                >
                  <div
                    style={{
                      width: '10px',
                      height: '10px',
                      backgroundColor: 'green',
                      borderRadius: '100%',
                    }}
                  ></div>
                  <h3 className={styles.optionsName}>
                    {params.name}
                    <span style={{ color: fontColors.greyDark }}>
                      &nbsp;@{params.username}
                    </span>
                  </h3>
                </div>
                {selectedOptions.some(elem => elem.id === params.id) ? (
                  <img src={selectedSign} />
                ) : (
                  <></>
                )}
              </div>
            );
          
        }
```

My issue is, when I try to change the bg-color of selected options, it resembles something like the following

[image]

I need the violet to be replaced by someother color, the code is nothing fancy,

```
              <div
                key={params.id}
                style={{
                  height: '40px',
                  display: 'flex',
                  width: '100%',

//This line is added
                  backgroundColor: 'yellow',
                  justifyContent: 'space-between',
                  alignItems: 'center',
                }}
              >
                <div
                  style={{
                    gap: '1rem',
                    alignItems: 'center',
                    display: 'flex',
                  }}
```

just to following line is added.

Can someone help me achieve an effect where the color of selected option is completely changed instead of overlayed? Thank you!

Comment: Add a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Where do all these violet colored options come from?